# How to assign variable in phpstorm for twig

Tags: twig, phpstorm

I have the following code:

```
<link href="{{ app.request.basepath }}/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Currently, php cannot find bootstrap.min.css as the location is web relative, not template location relative.

What do i add to my twig template or phpstorm to get phpstorm to understand that my basepath is '../../web/' ?

Comment: Are you using Symfony2?

Comment: Rightclick on the web folder in the project tree view - mark directory as - resource root.

Comment: @Maerlyn, your comment was right :) thank you. Can you rewrite it as an 'answer' so i can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPStorm's asset path and name completion works relative to the directories marked as resource root. You can also select these while creating the project, of afterwards like this:

- on the left (the project panel) rightclick on the web dir
- select mark directory as -> resource root